# CSS not selecting child elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am currently trying to select the list elements in my navigation bar and float them right, however for some reason the list elements aren't floating to the right. Any idea why?

html:

```
 <body>

    <header>
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
            <!--Navbar items-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Javascript files should be linked at the bottom of the page-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"; integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"; integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"; integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body{
  background:#262733;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: you  also use `.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float: right;
}` tha's because list going to right

Comment: you are using bootstrap, so did you check if you have some CSS in conflict

Comment: @TemaniAfif I am currently using the CDN do I need to download bootstrap to see if I have some css in conflict?

Answer (score 2):

The order is wrong. It should be `.navbar-nav .nav-item` if you want to select the `.nav-item` inside the `.navbar-nav` element. So correct code would be

```
body{
  background:#262733;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use your ul class (navbar-nav) and simply target the li elements in that class.

```
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list elements are floating right just fine, but you didn't quite go far enough. First I set list-style to none for the ul, then the li's I gave some left margin to separate them a bit. Style these as you see fit, I changed your dark background so you can see it a bit better:

```css
 body{
  background: #efefef;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
list-style: none;
}

li.nav-item {
margin: 0 0 0 1em;
}

.navbar-nav .nav-item {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
        <!--Navigation bar-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-light">
            <!--Navbar items-->
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--Javascript files should be linked at the bottom of the page-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"; integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"; integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"; integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but I wanted the items in my navigation bar to go all the way to the right side of the screen. Is float not the right thing to use to accomplish that?

Comment: They are doing that, unless you don't want them horizontally but vertically instead?